# codeigniter not detecting any controllers

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

i am using codeigniter 3.  i have created a simple controller and when i try to access the controller am getting the 404 error.

**my controller**

```
        <?php
        defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

        class home extends CI_Controller {

            /**
             * Index Page for this controller.
             *
             * Maps to the following URL
             *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
             *  - or -
             *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
             *  - or -
             * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
             * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
             *
             * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
             * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
             * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
             */
            public function index()
            {
                echo "Working fine";
                $this->load->view('comman/header.php');
                $this->load->view('home/home.php');

            }
        }
```

**config file**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/annaiplan/';

$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';

$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

**.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /annaiplan
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\\.php|resources|robots\\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

when i try to access the app  am getting 404 error.

```
http://localhost/annaiplan/home/
```

[image]

Comment: try the url like this:http://localhost/annaiplan/index.php/home/

Comment: @NirajKarmick that way it works.

Comment: You can check [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how%20to%20remove%20index.php%20in%20codeigniter&oq=how%20to%20remove%20index.php%20&ie=UTF-8&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.13320j0j7&sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.&bvm=bv.108194040,d.dGY&biw=1360&bih=659&dpr=1&ech=1&psi=ngZQVr6ZG8jLmAXI-p34Bw.1448085151548.3&ei=ngZQVr6ZG8jLmAXI-p34Bw&emsg=NCSR&noj=1) for removing `index.php` from url

Answer (score 1):

first always controller file name should be 'Home' and in class its class name should be Home extends.... second you need to change default controller from routes.php 
 path to rout.php ==== 
    root folder/application/config/routes.php

change from `$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';`to `$route['default_controller'] = 'Home`';

Comment: Thank you. this way it works. but when i try 'http://localhost/annaiplan/testing' then again 404 error.

Comment: you  need to write like localhost/aanaiplan/index.php/yourControllerName

Comment: ya but why index.php. why is my htaccess not working.

Comment: to resolve you need to change your htaccess.php file default provided file in codeigniter has config like that we need to use index.php vote up if way i suggested works for you!! Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

In htaccess file

Change:

```
RewriteBase /annaiplan
```

To:

```
RewriteBase /
```

And you can also replace htaccess code with this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|uploads|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```